# How do I load a field of a product in a custom module?

Tags: 8, commerce

A customer want to have the possibility to use different discounts on products. I'm working with the price resolver and I'll give the possibility to manage different discounts with taxonomy terms. I added an entity reference field (field_discount) to the product.

I'm writing the module that should look which discount is given to the product and then calculate the price based on the discount.

How can I load the value of *field_discount* in my module?

I made now a lot of research and I tried many different things, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
$product->get('field_discount')->entity
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$product->field_discount->value
```